# Scrollable window Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, interface, window, scrollbar

We created a browser on tkinter with a first window asking the user to enter criteria for a research. But for the results window, we have a problem. We can't scroll down on the window, even if there is more results below. How can we add a scroll bar? We tried this:

We tried this:

```
result_window = Tk()
    result_window.geometry("1080x600")
    result_window.minsize(480,360)
    my_canvas= Canvas(result_window)
    my_canvas.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=1)
    swin = Scrollbar(result_window, orient=VERTICAL, command=my_canvas.yview)
    swin.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
    my_canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=swin)
    my_canvas.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: my_canvas.configure(scrollregion =my_canvas.bbox("all")))
```

It is not working, do we actually need to use a canvas?

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: This looks like it should work, assuming you only want to scroll canvas items (text, rectangles, lines, ovals, images, ...). Your example seems incomplete since it doesn't show how you're creating any items on the canvas.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
result_window = Tk()
    result_window.geometry("1080x600")
    result_window.minsize(480,360)
    my_canvas= Canvas(result_window)
    my_canvas.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=1)
    swin = ttk.Scrollbar(result_window, orient=VERTICAL, command=my_canvas.yview)
    swin.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
    my_canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=swin.set)
    my_canvas.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: my_canvas.configure(scrollregion =my_canvas.bbox("all")))
```

You forgot to set the scrollcommand

```
my_canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=swin.set)
```

And I always put `ttk.` here `swin = ttk.Scrollbar(result_window, orient=VERTICAL, command=my_canvas.yview)` because it avoids some problems with other functions